# VSTS CI/CD Pipeline NetStandard Subdirectory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

I am completely new to VSTS CI Pipeline, and when I say completely new, I'm talking about 4 hours in.

I'm trying to setup an automated build on one of my subdirectories in my projects directory,and upon successful build, create nuget packages and have them pushed to my internal "Package Management" extension I setup earlier. So effectively a private repo for internal use packages.

The problem I am having, is that when I start my build (save and queue), It starts checking out every single file, in every folder, of every single project I have checked in (I am watching the console/build). Most of these are say full .net framework, WCF services/fill in the blank here and are completely irrelevant to the projects in question, thus I cannot see the point of what is happening.

So;
1) Is this normal, and ultimately, how do I limit this checkout process to only the directories and subsequent subdirectories I am trying to build the pipe for?

2) How do I only build projects under a certain sub-directory, which in turn contains its own folders/projects

So Example:

$AllProjects/NetStandard/Utils/* where * contains multiple project folders

Util1
Util2
...
UtilN

I have used the .Net Core Template, due to the libraries under the folder in questions all being NetStandard.

Apologies for the seemingly awkward question, but again, this is quite literally brand new to me.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using TFVC, not Git.

On the Get Sources step, you need to set your [workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/tfvc/optimize-your-workspace?view=vsts) mappings. Workspace mappings allow you to specify which locations in source control should be synchronized.

Comment: Hi Daniel, This wasn't actually the issue. I figured it out not long after you sent me this. Because I am so new to all this, I didnt realise that in the "Get Sources" part of of my build pipeline, that I had my server path set to the root $/AllProjects - and then under the build part I was trying to go /NetStandard/**/*.csproj or whatever. - I did however, fix up my workspace mappings as per your suggestion nonetheless - OR maybe it was the issue, and BECAUSE I fixed my mappings it then worked and I could be more selective about my sub folders.